VBA To Parse Userform Name In Method
I am trying to write less code by learning how to use OOP method. Its been a bit rough for me and have stuck. I would like to know how i will be able to parse the string name of my Userform. I have the following codes in my module called md_AddCountry.
`Sub Select_AddDonor_Country()
 Dim showsql As New cls_DBConPath

 With showsql
     .colname = "country_Name"
     .sqlst = "Select country_Name From ccf_country;"
     .formname = "frmAddDonor.cmbAddDonr_Country"
     .DBConPath

Set showsql = Nothing
End With
End Sub`

i have the following codes in my class module called cls_DBConPath
`Option Explicit
 Private psqlSt As String
 Private pcolumnName As String
 Private pform As Object
 Private pformName As String

 Public Property Get colname() As String
 colname = pcolumnName
 End Property

 Public Property Let colname(Value As String)
 pcolumnName = Value
 End Property

 Public Property Get sqlst() As String
 sqlst = psqlSt
 End Property

 Public Property Let sqlst(Value As String)
 psqlSt = Value
 End Property

 Public Property Get formname() As String
 formname = pformName
 End Property

 Public Property Let formname(Value As String)
 pformName = Value
 End Property

 Public Property Get form() As Object
 form = pform
 End Property

 Public Property Let form(Value As Object)
 pform = Value
 End Property`

`Sub DBConPath()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbPath As String
Dim fName As Object

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

dbPath = frmCCFDashboard.DBAddress.Caption

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open dbPath

Set rs = con.Execute(sqlst)

While rs.EOF = False

UserForms.Add(formname).AddItem rs.Fields(colname).Value
UserForms.Add(formname).AddItem rs.Fields(colname).Value
rs.MoveNext

Wend

End Sub  `

I keep on getting an error message of "Object Required" whenever i try parsing the name of my userform in the method i have created above. I will be grateful if you guys can help me on how to parse my userform in the method.
Please forgive me if you find my codes weird. I am trying to learn how to use class and its a whole mouth full for me. I am still grasping the concept

Your formname is not just the name of a form, it's the name of a control on the form as well, so you can't use it with userforms.add

I'm not sure if I'm entirely understanding the end goal of your code.
From what I'm reading in your md_AddCountry Select_AddDonor_Country subroutine, the goal is to pass string references to a class with those properties and then execute a sql query method using those properties and display the results to a userforms' controls with other properties defined in the objects construction.
It seems you also want the object to be instantiated and cleaned up by the with statement and you have some form object property which I assume is meant to be set as a form to display the content to. I also want to assume you're making this module public to run from the macros button on the excel developer ribbon.
The good news is you're not far off! Classes can be very powerful once mastered and trying OOP in VBA is very useful. This is my first SA answer! We're all doing something new. Hopefully, I use this answer section correctly.
'md_AddCountry
Sub Select_AddDonor_Country()

 With New cls_DBConPath 'you don't need to new the class if you are disposing it
     .colname = "country_Name"
     .sqlst = "Select country_Name From ccf_country;"
     .formname = "frmAddDonor.cmbAddDonr_Country"
     set .form = new frmAddDonor 'if you want to pass the userform to your class
     .DBConPath
     .form.show 'if you want to show your new prepopulated form
 End With

End Sub

'cls_DBConPath
Option Explicit
Private psqlSt As String
Private pcolumnName As String
Private pform As Object
Private pformName As String

Public Property Get colname() As String
 colname = pcolumnName
End Property

Public Property Let colname(Value As String)
 pcolumnName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get sqlst() As String
 sqlst = psqlSt
End Property

Public Property Let sqlst(Value As String)
 psqlSt = Value
End Property

Public Property Get formname() As String
 formname = pformName
End Property

Public Property Let formname(Value As String)
 pformName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get form() As Object 'objects need to be set'
 set form = pform
End Property

Public Property Set form(Value As Object) 'objects need to be set
 set pform = Value
End Property

Sub DBConPath()
  Dim con As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim dbPath As String
  Dim fName As Object

  'Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'you don't need to set here
  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  dbPath = frmCCFDashboard.DBAddress.Caption

  Set con = New ADODB.Connection 'if you set down here
  con.Open dbPath

  Set rs = con.Execute(sqlst)
  
  Dim control_name as string
  control_name = split(formname, ".")(1) 'split takes a delimiter and creates an
                                         'array; (1) takes the 2nd item of the
                                         'zero based array; (0) would get the
                                         'formname
  While rs.EOF = False
    
    form.Controls(control_name).AddItem rs.Fields(colname).Value '*
    'UserForms.Add(formname).AddItem rs.Fields(colname).Value 'not sure why the
    rs.MoveNext                                               'second one

  Wend

End Sub

*I replaced Userforms.Add, (which I think is used to dynamically add a userform. If that's your goal the above is not the right answer) , with form.Controls. This uses the newly instantiated userform previously passed into the class, that has yet to been shown but exists in memory. Then pass the control_name into the Controls collection and add that fields value!

thanks. I appreciate your solution. It works to the point where the code reads <control_name = split(formname, ".")(1)>. I get the error "Out of Stack Space". Can you explain what the (1) does? Do i replace it with the form contol ".cmbUpdateDonor_Country"? I am a bit confused with that part. But i appreciate your solution. Thanks

I'm not familiar with the "Out of Stack Space" error. I'm not sure why it would break there with that error either. The split function accepts a string and a delimiter and will return a zero based array of strings with each element being the text between delimiters.
The (1) is used to return the 2nd item of that zero based array.
You should be able to run <? split("frmAddDonor.cmbAddDonr_Country", ".")(1)> in the immediate window and the return should be "cmbAddDonr_Country". If you change it to <? split("frmAddDonor.cmbAddDonr_Country", ".")(0)>, it should return "frmAddDonor".

Yh running the code line in the immediate window displays correctly. My main reason for wanting to parse the userform name into the sql method is that i will be calling that method blue print in many other forms. I don't want to directly have the name of the form and its controls in the method. This will then be just the same as me repeating the same method codes for any other form that will run that procedure. Because if i replace the <form.Controls(control_name)> in the method with <frmAddDonor.cmbAddDonr_Country> the whole thing works fine.

Your code works correctly if i step through them using F8. But if i decide to call the module subroutine of 'Select_AddDonor_Country' in my form "frmAddDonor" at the initialization stage in runtime, i get the "Out of Stack Space" error. May be i am not calling the module procedure correctly

I managed to make it work. The code line 'Set .form = New frmAddDonor' opens the userform. So if i call the procedure "Select_AddDonor_Country" in my userform during initialization, it throws a recursion which upon my research is one of the reasons for getting an "Out of Stack Space" error. So i removed the "New" and just used 'Set .form = frmAddDonor' and it worked fine. Thanks bro

Oh that makes perfect sense! Glad I was able to get you in the right direction! Side note that's a little more advanced, (could also be overkill) you could try to use an Interface for your class objects to implement if they're all going to have the same properties and methods. An Interface acts like a contract and allows composition in VBA OOP. If you haven't found rubberduckvba yet, I would read some of the blogs, here is the one directly covering classes and interfaces: https://rubberduckvba.blog/2019/07/08/about-class-modules/

Yeah. I have been reading and watching videos around class interfaces. Will check the link out and learn more. One last question. Can the class i have created "cls_DBPath" be used by many different sub routines that will be run in different Userforms? If it can, will there be any challenge? I hope my question makes sense. Hahahaha. Thanks

Absolutely, and by using the 'with new Class: end with' syntax in your sub routines, you don't need to worry about the instantiation or termination of your class objects. They only exist in the context of the with block and are effectively garbage collected once the execution leaves the scope of the with block. The reason to use the 'new' keyword, is to ensure the Class we're working with is not a previously instantiated Class set elsewhere. That way your Userforms are able to user the same functionality of the class, without affecting each other's use of the class.

It is far easier to use an existing (empty) userform for something like this. Make sure the form contains controls (and their code) that are common to the tasks the form needs to be able to do (like a caption label, OK/Cancel buttons, record selection buttons, etcetera). Add everything else at runtime. This means any event code needed for the runtime added controls needs to go in separate classes which are instantiated with the addition of those controls.
If the variation between what needs to go on the form in different circumstances isn't very big, consider placing everything on the form and hiding stuff that isn't needed. Makes writing event code simpler and you have more events to work with. Not OOP, but sometimes limitations in the language force you to do less elegant things.
